# How to show progress of import-csv whilst piping to DataTable?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following snippet to import CSV data into a DataTable, which I use to bulkload into a SQL table. It's been working fine, but recently I've been receiving larger and larger csv files to load and so I've noticed the operation can take about 1.5-2 hours to complete (for a 150MB CSV file), before it starts bulk loading (which takes about 10-20 mins...pretty reasonable for bulk load).

```
$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv $csvFile | Out-DataTable
```

Since the operation takes long to import, I'd like to add some sort of indication of where the import process is at. I've tried the following:

```
$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv $csvFile | % -begin {$i=0} -process { Write-Progress -activity "Importing file" -currentOperation "Reading line $i" -PercentComplete -1; $i++ } | Out-DataTable
```

However, I've noticed the operation time is almost doubled and not only that, but it seems like piping to the DataTable is ignored (i.e. the Datatable doesn't get populated anymore).

How can I make it show progress AND load in the DataTable?

I've also considered other options like streamreader, though I'm getting error:

```
[int]$LinesInFile = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $csvFile
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { $LinesInFile++ }

$CSVDataTable = 0..($LinesInFile-1) | foreach {
    $percent = ($_/$LinesInFile)*100
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Importing from CSV' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Importing row # $($_+1)" -PercentComplete $percent;
    return $reader[$_]
} | Import-Csv $csvFile | Out-DataTable
```

Error (due to `return $reader[$_]`):

```
Import-Csv : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already looks good, off the top of my head I couldn't think about a better solution that's easy to implement.

As to why `Foreach-Object` is slow, I recommend this article: [Speeding up the pipeline](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline). It also shows how to write a faster foreach method:

```bsh
function Foreach-ObjectFast
{
  param
  (
    [ScriptBlock]
    $Process,
    
    [ScriptBlock]
    $Begin,
    
    [ScriptBlock]
    $End
  )
  
  begin
  {
    # construct a hard-coded anonymous simple function from
    # the submitted scriptblocks:
    $code = @"
& {
  begin
  {
    $Begin
  }
  process
  {
    $Process
  }
  end
  {
    $End
  }
}
"@
    # turn code into a scriptblock and invoke it
    # via a steppable pipeline so we can feed in data
    # as it comes in via the pipeline:
    $pip = [ScriptBlock]::Create($code).GetSteppablePipeline()
    $pip.Begin($true)
  }
  process 
  {
    # forward incoming pipeline data to the custom scriptblock:
    $pip.Process($_)
  }
  end
  {
    $pip.End()
  }
}
```

Finally, the reason why your output doesn`t reach` Out-DataTable` - of course, you have to send the current item back into the pipeline, somewhat like this:

```
Write-Progres ....
return $_ # or $PSItem
```

Comment: interesting! as for returning the item back to pipeline, so essentially like this? `$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv $csvFile | % -begin {$i=0} -process { Write-Progress -activity "Importing file" -currentOperation "Reading line $i" -PercentComplete -1; $i++; return $_ } | Out-DataTable`

Comment: i am trying this out with streamreader: `[int]$LinesInFile = 0
  $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $csvFile
  $line = $reader.ReadLine()
  while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { $LinesInFile++ }

  $CSVDataTable = 0..($LinesInFile-1) | foreach {
   $percent = ($_/$LinesInFile)*100
   Write-Progress -Activity 'Importing from CSV' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Importing row # $($_+1)" -PercentComplete $percent;
   return $line[$_]
  } | Import-Csv $csvFile | Out-DataTable` but error: `Import-Csv : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command`

Comment: @Cataster Try out the first solution for now and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out this function I hacked together (needs improvement!) It uses a .NET StreamReader for reading, reports progress, and writes everything directly into `ConvertFrom-Csv`. Also let me know, how the speed of this compares to the other solution.

```bsh
function Import-CsvProgress {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [char]
        $Delimiter = ";"
    )
    begin {
        try {
            $length = (Get-Item $Path).Length
            $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader ]::new($Path)
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\ConvertFrom-Csv', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $params = @{
                Delimiter = $Delimiter
            }
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @params }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline()
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($true)
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
    process {
        try {
            while (-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
                $percentComplete = $reader.BaseStream.Position * 100 / $length
                Write-Progress "Importing $Path" -PercentComplete $percentComplete -Status $percentComplete
                $steppablePipeline.Process($reader.ReadLine())
            }
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
        finally {
            $reader.Dispose()
        }
    }
    end {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
            $reader.Dispose()
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Import-CsvProgress -Path $csvFile -Delimiter ";" | Out-DataTable
```

Comment: oh this is awesome! as far as speed, i tried a 132KB comma delimited csv file with 3073 records, and it took 1 minute and 20 seconds using this function. Using the other solution, it took 56 seconds to complete. However, using @mklement0 solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758391/8397835 took only 5 seconds to complete!