# How to return current item back to the pipeline?

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

Im currently importing csv files and bulk loading to sql table.

using this code

```
$CSVDataTable = Import-Csv $csvFile | % -begin {$i=0} -process { Write-Progress -activity "Importing file" -currentOperation "Reading line $i" -PercentComplete -1; $i++; return $_ } | Out-DataTable
```

i am able to show the progress, but I'd like to optimize it and one recommendation Ive found is utilizing StreamReader.

so ive tried the following:

```
[int]$LinesInFile = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $csvFile
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { $LinesInFile++ }

$CSVDataTable = 0..($LinesInFile-1) | foreach {
    $percent = ($_/$LinesInFile)*100
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Importing from CSV' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Importing row # $($_+1)" -PercentComplete $percent;
    return $reader[$_]
} | Import-Csv $csvFile | Out-DataTable
```

Error (due to `return $reader[$_]`):

```
Import-Csv : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that makes sense to pipe to `Import-Csv` are `System.IO.FileInfo` instances representing CSV *files*, such as output by `Get-ChildItem` (which, as an aside, is broken due to a bug in Windows PowerShell, since fixed in PowerShell [Core] v6+).

If you want to report on the progress of an `Import-Csv` call, put a `ForEach-Object` command *after* it, in which you can emit the progress message and then pass `Import-Csv`'s output object (`$_`) through:

```
# Count the data rows in the input CSV file.
$rowCount = 0
switch -File $csvFile { default { ++$rowCount } }
--$rowCount # subtract 1 from the line count to account for the header row.

Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 0 } {

  $percent = '{0:N1}' -f (++$i / $rowCount * 100)
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Importing from CSV' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Importing row # $i" -PercentComplete $percent

  $_  # pass the object from Import-Csv through.

} | Out-DataTable

# Hide the progress bar now.
# (Otherwise it would linger until the script as a whole completes.)
Write-Progress '(unused))' -Completed
```

---

It's worth noting that **per-object `Write-Progress` calls significantly slow down execution** (and counting the number of lines up front has its cost too, as does even just passing objects through via a `ForEach-Object` call).

A simple way to mitigate the slowdown is to **only use `Write-Progress` for every N objects**, such as every `100` objects in the following example:

```
# Count the data rows in the input CSV file.
$rowCount = 0
switch -File $csvFile { default { ++$rowCount } }
--$rowCount # subtract 1 from the line count to account for the header row.

Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object -Begin { $i = 0 } {

  if (++$i % 100 -eq 1 -or $i -eq $rowCount) {
    $percent = '{0:N1}' -f ($i / $rowCount * 100)
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Importing from CSV' -Status "$percent % Complete" -CurrentOperation "Importing row # $i" -PercentComplete $percent
  }

  $_  # pass the object from Import-Csv through.

} | Out-DataTable

# Hide the progress bar now.
# (Otherwise it would linger until the script as a whole completes.)
Write-Progress '(unused))' -Completed
```

Note: If `Out-DataTable` requires a nontrivial amount of processing time after the last object has been passed to it, you could pad the number of rows for the purpose of the percentage display based on an *estimate* of that additional time, as a percentage of the true row count.

Comment: This is exactly what I too am looking for. Thanks, mklement0. However, I could not make any sense out of the 'note' you've mentioned at the end of the post.

Comment: My query #2 is, can we use a similar approach to show progress when we run the `Get-ADUser -Filter { ... }` command where the resulting count of users is not static or is my query just absurd?

Comment: @KarthickGanesan: The note at the bottom of the answer applies to the case where you have an additional pipeline segment that requires additional processing time: if you limit the progress display to the processing time of the `ForEach-Object` segment and the final segment takes a nontrivial amount of to finish processing the last input object, the progress display will be stuck at 100% for a while, which will be frustrating to users. Hence the suggestion to increase the denominator of the percent-complete to account for the additional processing time, which, however, requires an _estimate_.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan: Re `Get-ADUser`: As long as the time it takes to process the result of a single `Get-ADUser` call doesn't vary too widely between calls, the progress display will still be helpful to end users, even if it is based on the number of calls. A progress display needn't be - and often cannot be - 100% linear in terms of _time_. If you have follow-up questions, please create a _new_ question post.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061705/optimize-get-aduser-filter). While my question is largely based on performance, courtesy of `Get-ADUser` cmdlet's `-Filter` criteria and some uncontrollable factors, I wonder if my use of Write-Progress is adding more trouble. We can discuss this further in my new post.