# Optimize Get-ADUser filter

Tags: powershell, active-directory, large-data

In AD, I'm trying to identify user accounts where the same EmployeeID value is populated in 2 or more records. Below is my piece of code (Credit: I'm using a `Show-Progress` function defined [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Progress/0.0.1/Content/Show-Progress.psm1)) and the `Get-ADUser` command alone has taken more than 2 hours to fetch all the records. The other steps (2 to 5) have been pretty quick. While I've completed the work, I'm trying to know if this could've been done more efficiently with PowerShell.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(ObjectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)(employeeid=*))" -Properties $properties -Server $server_AD_GC -ResultPageSize 1000 | 
    # *ISSUE HERE*
    #    The Get-ADUser extract process seems to work very slow.
    #    However, it is important to note that the above command will be retrieving more than 200K records
    # NOTE: I've inferred that employeeid is an indexed attribute and is replicated to GlobalCatalogs and hence have used it in the filter
    Show-Progress -Activity "(1/5) Getting AD Users ..." |
select $selectPropsList -OutVariable results_UsersBaseSet |
Group-Object EmployeeID | 
    Show-Progress -Activity "(2/5) Grouping on EmployeeID ..." | 
? { $_.Count -gt 1 } | 
    Show-Progress -Activity "(3/5) Filtering only dup EmpID records ..." | 
select -Exp Group | 
    Show-Progress -Activity "(4/5) UnGrouping ..." | 
Export-Csv "C:\Users\me\op_GetADUser_w_EmpID_Dupes_EntireForest - $([datetime]::Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss")).csv" -NoTypeInformation |
    Show-Progress -Activity "(5/5) Exporting ..." | 
Out-Null
```

PS: I've also tried to first export all the user accounts to a csv file and then post-process with Excel but I had to frown because of the size of the dataset and it was both time and memory crunching.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: see if this of any help https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/optimize-performance-of-ad-ds-queries-via-powershell/

Comment: Thanks, TheGameiswar, that's a useful link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't know what is in `$properties` or `$selectPropsList`, your question is really only about finding out to which users the same EmployeeID has been issued, right?
By default, Get-ADUser already returns these properties:

`DistinguishedName`, `Enabled`, `GivenName`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `SamAccountName`, `SID`, `Surname`, `UserPrincipalName`

So all you need extra is the EmployeeID I guess.  Trying to collect LOTS of properties does slow down, so keeping this to a bare minimum helps to speed things up.

Next, by using the `Show-Progress` script you have linked to, you will slow down the execution of the script considerably. Do you really need to have a progress bar?
Why not simply write the lines with activity steps directly to the console?

Also, piping everything together doesn't help in the speed department either..

```
$server_AD_GC    = 'YourServer'
$selectPropsList = 'EmployeeID', 'Name', 'SamAccountName', 'Enabled'
$outFile         = "C:\Users\me\op_GetADUser_w_EmpID_Dupes_EntireForest - $([datetime]::Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmss")).csv"

Write-Host "Step (1/4) Getting AD Users ..." 
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -like '*'" -Properties EmployeeID -Server $server_AD_GC -ResultPageSize 1000

Write-Host "Step (2/4) Grouping on EmployeeID ..."
$dupes = $users | Group-Object -Property EmployeeID | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }

Write-Host "Step (3/4) Collecting duplicates ..."
$result = foreach ($group in $dupes) {
    $group.Group | Select-Object $selectPropsList
}

Write-Host "Step (4/4) Exporting ..."
$result | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host  "All done" -ForegroundColor Green
```

<sup>P.S. `Get-ADUser` already returns user objects only, so there is no need for the LDAP filter `(ObjectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)`. Using `-Filter "EmployeeID -like '*'"` is probably faster</sup>

Comment: Thanks Theo! The suggestions you've provided here are helpful. I should've mentioned in my question that I'm required to extract about 20 properties from the target user objects (includes title, dept, company, office, manager, and some more). And, my ask from `Write-Progress`, while expecting 200K+ objects, was just to know that `Get-ADUser` is still returning objects. As I've mentioned in my OP, after the 1st step the remaining ones were fairly quick. Now, I'll try modifying my filter and eliminate `Show-Progress` as per your suggestion and will post back on performance.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan Especially when you have to deal with so many user objects, I would keep this first run of `Get-ADUser` as lean as possible. When determining the users that have a common EmployeeID, you'd probably disregard most of them so it is a waste of resources to get all these properties to start with. I would use the filtered users inside `$result` to do more processing on only that subset of users. This will mean extra looping through the users you now have, but since there are (hopefully) just a few, this should be faster than retrieving it all for users you will not use anyway.

Comment: Wow, this is truly a very good suggestion. I infer from your point that I should use another `Get-ADUser` to pull all the required attributes only for those target user objects that have been filtered into the $result variable. This is so good! ✌

Comment: @KarthickGanesan Yes, that was the idea. Actually, it would even be easier to get the rest of the properties using the `$dupes` array from step 2 (like a step 2.5). Then all other steps can remain as-is

Answer (score 1):

This answer complements [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062329/45375) and **focuses on *showing progress* during the operation**:

- The [linked `Show-Progress` function](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Progress/0.0.1/Content/Show-Progress.psm1), which is the latest as of this writing:

  - has an outright *bug*, in that it doesn't pass pipeline input through (the relevant line is accidentally commented out)
  - is conceptually flawed in that it doesn't use a `process` block, which means that *all pipeline input is collected first*, before it is processed - which defeats the idea of a progress bar.
- Therefore, you `Show-Progress` calls won't show progress until the previous command in the pipeline has output *all* of its output. A simple alternative is to break the pipeline into separate commands and to simply emit *one* progress message *before* each command, announcing the next *stage* of processing (rather than per-object progress) as shown in Theo's answer.
- Generally, there is no way to show the progress of *command-internal* processing, only the progress of a command's (multi-object) *output*.

  - The simplest way to do this via a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call in which you call
    [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress), but that comes with two challenges:

    - In order to show a *percent-complete* progress bar, *you need to know how many objects there will be in total*, which you must determine *ahead of time*, because a *pipeline* cannot know how many objects it will receive; your only option is to *collect all output first* (or find some other way to count it) and then use the collected output as pipeline input, using the count of objects as the basis for calculating the value to pass to `Write-Progress -PerCentComplete`.
    - Calling `Write-Progress` for *each* object received will result in a *significant slowdown* of overall processing; a compromise is to only call it for every N objects, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758391/45375); the approach there could be wrapped in a properly implemented function a la `Show-Progress` that requires passing the total object count as an argument and performs proper *streaming* input-object processing (via a `process` block); that said, the mere act of using *PowerShell code* for passing input objects through is costly.

---

**Conclusion:**

***Percent-complete* progress displays have two inherent problems**:

- They require you to know the total number of objects to process *beforehand* (a pipeline has no way of knowing how many objects will pass through it):

  - Either: *Collect* all objects to process *in memory*, *beforehand*, if feasible; the count of elements in the collection can then serve as the basis for the percent-complete calculations. This may not be an option with very large input sets.
  - Or: Perform an extra processing step beforehand that merely *counts* all objects without actually retrieving them. This may not be practical in terms of the additional processing time added.
- Object-by-object processing in *PowerShell code* - either via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) or an [advanced script/function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) - is inherently slow.

  - You can mitigate that somewhat by limiting [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) calls to every N objects, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758391/45375)

Overall it's a **tradeoff between processing speed and the ability to show percent-complete progress** to the end user.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, it is always a delight to see an answer from you. It has many a times helped me fine-tune my PS scripting capabilities. However, to my own fault of still remaining a novice in PS, I've had some drift recently.
1) The bug - I've uncommented the object passthru `$_` line
2) The conceptual flaw - Right under the nose, thanks for pointing this out.
3) Place the `Show-Progress` call before the command - I thought the current command should be piped to `Show-Progress` for it to display progress bar
4) ...

Comment: ... 4) Counting output objects before using pipeline - I see this cannot be done and there is no workaround either. Or, is there some way, esp. with `Get-ADUser`, of knowing just the count without retrieving the objects in the first place? Sorry for being dumb.
5) Call `Write-Progress` only for every N objects - accepted; probably, atleast every 1/10th count.
**Conclusion:** It is basically bad to use `Write-Progress` along with an object passthru as it only increases processing time.

Comment: Thank you for the nice feedback, @KarthickGanesan. Re 3) - my  bad: yes, with `Show-Progress` that won't work; I've rewritten the paragraph, which now explicitly mentions Theo's alternative: breaking the pipeline into multiple commands, and restricting the progress information to announcing each stage of processing as a whole. Re 4) No, you can't know the count in advance, but if all objects fit into memory, simply collect them in an array beforehand, as shown in Theo's answer (`$users = Get-ADUser  ...`), from which you can derive the count ahead of time.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan: Re 5) and conclusion: Yes, it definitely slows things down, and even though limiting the `Write-Progress` calls to every N objects helps, the mere fact of using PowerShell code to simply pass objects through is inherently slow. It's a tradeoff between processing speed and the ability to show percent-complete progress to the end user.